# Angular Routing does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

My angular routing is not working (clicking link does not cause route change):

```
var smu72App = angular.module("smu72App", [
        "ngRoute"
]).
    config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "/templates/home.html",
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
            .when("/objects", {
                templateUrl: "/templates/objects.html",
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
            .when("/object/:Id", {
                templateUrl: '/templates/object.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

That's main page that hold ng-view (cutted a bit for better reading):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="smu72App">
....
    <base href="/">
 .....
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">
   ...
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> //THAT'S SCROLLSPY LINKS (NOT ANGULAR)
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services"> УСЛУГИ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio"> OБЪЕКТЫ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about-us"> OТЗЫВЫ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#certificates"> СЕРТИФИКАТЫ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact"> КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  ...
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/simplbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:25018/Scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:25018/Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:25018/Scripts/smu72Controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `smu72App.config` instead of `var smu72App = agular.module("smu72App", ["ngRoute"]).config`
Hope this help.

Comment: It's not working as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your module first

```
angular.module("smu72App", ["ngRoute"]);
```

Then initialize config

```
angular.module("smu72App").config("....ur routes in here");
```

Are you getting any console errors?

I have noticed one morething that ur anchor tag href doesn't match with the routes in ur config section except ur home page and that is why ur home page is loading fine.

Just an example try ur anchor tag like this `<a href="#/about">` or like `<a href="/about">` coz i think ur not using hash
and create ur route like below

```
$routeProvider.when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
    });
```

Comment: No, there is no errors in console, as well as this is not working.

Comment: Are you getting your home.html page??

Comment: Yes, default template (home.html) are loading fine, but links to the other templates aren't working.

Comment: Updated my answer by looking at the code ur have provided ur href attribute doesn't match up with the routes you have mentioned in config section

Comment: Is it compatible with html5mode?